# Resources for 2 Particle Irreducible (2PI) or Cornwall-Jackiw-Tomboulis (CJT) formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, 1pi-effective-action

I'am currently learning the 2 particle irreducible (2PI) or Cornwall-Jackiw-Tomboulis (CJT) formalism. Does anybody know a textbook or a review that treats this subject? As far I only found the original papers like 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.10.2428
but no modern review. Of course there are a lot of papers that use this formalism, but I haven't found a general introduction yet.

As far I know how to compute the generating functional, but not why this is a useful approximation, where it can be used (limits of the framework) and so on. At the end I am interested in renormalization in the Hartree approximation
(I have resources for that, but not for the "beginning")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an extensive, survey-like introduction by [Juergen Berges](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0409233), dating from 2004. For the renormalization of 2PI effective actions see also
a very [recent paper by Carrington et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0710).